# Change the amount of content displayed per page in Content Management -> Content

Tags: 6, nodes, importing-exporting

I'm trying to do a CSV export of all my content, but it only shows 50 per page and I have 50+ pages. I want to be able to check all and export as one csv. Is there a way to change the pagination settings for Content Management -> Content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Views to generate a list of all your contents, create a new view of type node, add fields what you like, then use [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) to export content list as CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view and directly export that as CSV with [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus).

However, with 50 * 50 nodes, you might run into memory problems if you try to display them all on a single page.

Comment: Hmm. How do I select CSV as the output? I have the bonus pack and I enabled Bonus: Views Export, but when I hit export on a view I get no options for how to export it.

Comment: Export is about exporting the configuration of the view. You need to change the output style, as explained in the README: http://drupalcode.org/project/views_bonus.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/export/README.txt

Comment: Crap. I didn't realize there more more README's nested in the folders. The top level one is totally useless. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if there's a setting that will make drupal not time out when there are a lot of nodes to export? I find my limit is about 400 before it breaks.

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote above. The more nodes, the more processing/memory it requires. That's simple math :) You could increase the time/memory limit, but you probably don't have access to this unless that is your own server. If so, then see http://drupal.org/node/207036 and http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time